# Should I give my new manager a copy of my resume in a one on one meeting?

Tags: communication, performance-reviews, meetings

I work in the US. The company encourages employees to initiate one on one monthly meetings with your manager. The goal is to have regular discussions and for your work progress to be documented over time so it's easier when the annual performance review comes around. I have had a new manager for about a month and am now on a new team. I also have new additional duties with this change. This manager gives me direction regarding work, but I really don't know her and she does not know me. She did not interview me and we never used to work together. I have been on the job about 7 months. From what I can see so far, she works hard and seems to know what she is doing which makes me comfortable to take direction from her.

Next Wednesday will be our first one on one meeting that I initiated. I'm supposed to let her know how things are going. Should I give her a copy of my resume so she has a better picture of my work background? I am also curious as to what is her background. Or is it best not to get too deep with her and to just let my work speak for itself?

Comment: I tend to assume my manager has access to my files and can see the resume... So I'd just say "hey, I'm curious about your background, and of course if you have any questions about mine I'd be glad to discuss it."

Comment: @keshlam - That's going to be highly company dependent. I've been in situations where I became someone's manager and didn't get get any of the past files -- no resume, performance reviews, etc.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Shrug. I'd still just ask the manager if they want a copy rather than dumping it on them, for clarity's sake. But de gustibus...

Comment: Based on other responses on here, I've decided not to give her the resume. I felt a little nervous a b out it anyway.

Answer (score 8):

> Next Wednesday will be our first one on one meeting that I initiated.
> I'm supposed to let her know how things are going. Should I give her a
> copy of my resume so she has a better picture of my work background?

No. A resume is for getting hired, not for getting to know your boss better.

Instead, talk. Let her know how things are going. During your discussion pay attention to hints as to what she wants to know about you and your work, and then tell her.

> I am also curious as to what is her background. Or is it best not to
> get too deep with her and to just let my work speak for itself?

Your work has nothing to do with her background.

During your conversation, look for clues as to how open she is about herself. If you sense that she is open, ask more about her background. Be friendly. Get to know each other.

Basically, use the one on one meeting to talk. You'll learn how she wants the meeting to proceed.

And don't wait a long time for your next meeting. Ask if you can meet monthly on a regular basis. This sort of meeting with your boss is important. When I was the manager, I had one on one meetings weekly.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was feeling a little nervous about giving a resume and exposing myself. I do have a lot to say on how things are going and things I would like to learn.

Comment: I had the one on one today. I thought it went well. I did not include the resume.

Answer (score 4):

No.

I, as a Manager, would likely interpret this as an implicit threat:

"My Resume is written and up-to-date, if I don't get what I want, I'm off"

What you want to do, is complete a Skills Matrix (if your company has a standard Skills Matrix template, even better, if not - just Google one and configure it as applicable).

This will let your manager know where your strengths *and your weaknesses* are and then when you have the conversation, you can refer her to the Matrix to expand on various issues.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I didn't realize it would be viewed that way. Glad I asked. I will Google the skills Matrix. Thank you.

Comment: And if you like the 99% percent of people, your resume is a complete lie (ok, *slight* of misrepresentation skills and experience designed to pass automated checkers and possibly impress actual recruiter) I'd avoid reminding other of that "document". :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov A Complete Lie? But one does occasionally take a little artistic licence... Logged into a particular network appliance a Year Ago? 1 years experience with that brand!

Comment: A resume isn't necessarily threatening. If that's what you have on hand that includes the background/skills you want to share, I don't know that it would be a problem. A skills matrix is a great alternative -- especially if there is a company standard template.

Comment: A good CV will show you in the best possible light without lying. We all know that, and future employers know that.

Answer (score 1):

If your company culture is one where the direct reports are the ones that are supposed to request these one-on-one meetings, then yay for you getting it scheduled!

A great, easily digestible resource for working with/being a manager is [Help! I have a manager!](https://wizardzines.com/zines/manager/) by Julia Evans.  I believe the preview page linked there covers 1:1 meetings and what to talk about.

In terms of sharing your resume or not, I would not assume that your new manager has seen (or read) any of the past documents on you that the company might have. This would include your resume, past performance review, or even past compensation changes. If you think sharing your background/current skills is important for them to understand, then something like a skills matrix as suggested in another response would be great. But if the only thing you have ready is a resume, that can work.

I'd also suggest that in addition to talking about the skills you have, it is important to let your new manager how you work best and what they can do to keep you productive. Are you someone that likes to have someone check-in on your work frequently or do you prefer to be largely independent and heads-down with defined check-in points? Do you like to get public acknowledgment or prefer to have your recognition be as part of the team? Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have decided to not give the resume and just assume she may have information about me. I was nervous about doing it any way. I will review the article Help I have a Manager. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, print out your resume. The cost of doing so is the cost of printing a couple of pieces of paper.  If it is clear it is not needed, then the cost was minor. But if you realize you needed it, then you have it.

The goal isn't to put it in front of them, it is only to have it ready in case they want it, or it becomes clear it would help the conversation.

I have worked for places where we were required to update our resume annually, and it was stored in company system. In other places you only gave the company a updated resume when they wanted to include it a contract proposal.

They weren't there when you started, your working relationship is new; it is possible that something in the resume may help them better deploy their resources.

I have run into situations in the past where management had no idea about the background of their employees because they inherited them. That meant they never knew that person X had experience doing Y, so they never went after work in that area because they felt they didn't have anybody that would understand it.